# Initialized string is different from concatenated string but same results when printing

Tags: java, regex, string, concatenation

So I am making a reg ex pattern and matcher for user input and I use concatenation to produce the string that will be used for Pattern.compile().
I cant match the pattern but when I print the result of the concatenation and put it inside the Pattern.compile, it matches the pattern. I tried different ways of concatenating but it still doesnt match.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        Matcher elementMatcher = element.matcher(inputArr[i]);
        if(elementMatcher.matches())    inputPattern += elemString;
        else if(inputArr[i].equals("+") || inputArr[i].equals("*") || inputArr[i].equals(".") || inputArr[i].equals("(")|| inputArr[i].equals(")") || inputArr[i].equals("-") || inputArr[i].equals("/")){
            inputPattern += "\\\\";
            inputPattern += inputArr[i];
        }   
        else inputPattern += inputArr[i];
        inputPattern += "\\\\s*";           
    }

    if(inputPattern.equals("[a-zA-Z]+\\s*\\+\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*"))    
    System.out.println(inputPattern); //prints [a-zA-Z]+\\s*\\+\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*
    pattern1 = Pattern.compile(inputPattern);
    matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(value[j]);
    if(matcher1.matches())  {
            result = value[j];
        System.out.println("YO");

    }
```

Strangely, it works when

```
pattern1 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+\\s*\\+\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*");
```

but printing inputPattern produces `[a-zA-Z]+\\s*\\+\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*` and

```
pattern1 = Pattern.compile(inputPattern);
```

produces different results

Comment: What is the question? Why you get `"\"` when print string literal `"\\"`?

Comment: @talex when i print the concatenated string it produces the same string i put in Pattern.compile but  Pattern.compile(inputPattern) is different from Pattern.compile([a-zA-Z]+\\s*\\+\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*) when inputPattern is [a-zA-Z]+\\s*\\+\\s*[a-zA-Z]+\\s*

Comment: Read about escape sequences. When your string literal contains `"\\"` string will contain only one slash.

Comment: Because litteral string in Java interpret `\ `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java have escape sequences in string literals. If string contains `\` that mean next character will be interpreted in special way.

To add `\` to string you need to escape it `"\\"`.

Here is some sample code:

```
String s = "\\";

System.out.println(s); // print single slash
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how to get the appropriate number of \ characters into the pattern string. To get a single \ character into a literal string you need to enter two: "\\" will give you a string with a single \ character. This string will print as \ . Hence if you have a string that prints as \\ , it may have been created using four \ in a literal string, as "\\\\" will print as \\ .

Usually it is best to try to simplify as much as possible to understand and fix such problems!